# How can I call a function after several callbacks have been called

Tags: javascript, angular-promise

I need to push the data into a new array from the database, which will return promise object. 5 times I need to call. So I do it like this.

```js
 var items = [];

 function setData() {
   facilityAPIs.getAllListItems.get({
     listName: "Samples"
   }).
   $promise.then(function(data) {
     alert("1");
     for (var j = 0; j < data.items.length; j++) {
       items.push(data.items[j]);
     }
     console.log(items);
   }).then(function() {
     facilityAPIs.getAllListItems.get({
       listName: "Controls"
     }).
     $promise.then(function(data) {
       alert("2");
       for (var j = 0; j < data.items.length; j++) {
         items.push(data.items[j]);
       }
       console.log(items);
     });
   }).then(function() {
     facilityAPIs.getAllListItems.get({
       listName: "FibroBlast"
     }).
     $promise.then(function(data) {
       alert("3");
       for (var j = 0; j < data.items.length; j++) {
         items.push(data.items[j]);
       }
       console.log(items);
     });
   }).then(function() {
     facilityAPIs.getAllListItems.get({
       listName: "pBMC"
     }).
     $promise.then(function(data) {
       alert("4");
       for (var j = 0; j < data.items.length; j++) {
         items.push(data.items[j]);
       }
       console.log(items);
     });
   }).then(function() {
     facilityAPIs.getAllListItems.get({
       listName: "iPS Cell Lines"
     }).
     $promise.then(function(data) {
       alert("5");
       for (var j = 0; j < data.items.length; j++) {
         items.push(data.items[j]);
       }
       console.log(items);
     });
   });
 }
```

But if I want to use items array after all of data are pushed into it, such as call splitData(items). how can I that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So is it something like this?

```
var items = [];

some_fn(...)
    .then(function(data) { [push data to items] })
    .then(function() {
        some_fn(...).then(function(data) { [push data to items] });
    })
    .then(function() {
        some_fn(...).then(function(data) { [push data to items] });
    })
    .then(function() {
        some_fn(...).then(function(data) { [push data to items] });
    })
    .then(function() {
        some_fn(...).then(function(data) { [push data to items] });
    })
    .then(function() {
        ...use items somehow after _all_ data has been pushed to it...
    })
```

If so, then the problem is that this "`.then` chain" isn't really a chain: the "top level `.then`"s will be executed one after another, but inside each of them you start a new asynchronous operation separately. Each of these will eventually push some data to items, but the end result cannot be captured in the last "`.then`".

If you simply attach multiple "fulfilled" callbacks to the same promise, and you don't return a promise from them, they will simply be execute one after the other, when your first promise is fulfilled:

```
promise
  .then(function() { foo; }  // will be executed when promise is fulfilled
  .then(function() { bar; }  // will be executed right after
```

If you run other async operations in your callbacks, and want to create a chain, you need to return a promise from the callback:

```
promise
   .then(function() { return promise_foo; }  // will be executed when promise is fulfilled
   .then(function() { return promise_bar; }  // will be executed when promise_foo is fulfilled
```

(For details, see The Promise Resolution Procedure in the [spec](https://promisesaplus.com/).)

So the original example could be reorganised like this to create a single chain:

```
some_fn(...)
    .then(function(data) { [push data to items] })
    .then(function() {
        return some_fn(...).then(function(data) { [push data to items] });
    })
    .then(function() {
        return some_fn(...).then(function(data) { [push data to items] });
    })
    .then(function() {
        return some_fn(...).then(function(data) { [push data to items] });
    })
    .then(function() {
        return some_fn(...).then(function(data) { [push data to items] });
    })
    .then(function() {
        ...all operations have finished, you can use items here...
    })
```